# UN's decision to publicly endorse a political candidate

Tags: united-nations, sovereignty

So based on the charter of the United Nations, Article 2, the organisation is based on the sovereign of every member and they will not take actions for domestic affairs (in this context, it is in a military way). So basically what I am trying to ask is that whether or not an endorsement is counted as an act of dispute towards the sovereignty of a country.

In other words, if the United Nations decides to publicly endorse a political candidate, do they contradict their own stance on respecting the sovereignty of a country?

Comment: If the UN endorsed a political candidate then it would almost definitely contravene point 7 of Article 2. However, I take it from your aside regarding military action that you mean something other than mere endorsement. Could you elaborate? Do you have a particular incident in mind that you could link to?

Comment: I find it unlikely the general assembly will ever endorse any candidate anywhere, but perhaps the ramifications of some official making some kind of statement would be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The United Nations has never endorsed any political candidate in the past as it is not specified in the purposes (Article 1) and principles (Article 2) of the United Nations' Charter. It will never happen in the future.

[Article 1: Purposes of the United Nations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapter_I_of_the_United_Nations_Charter)

> Article 2, clause 7 of this chapter reemphasizes the fact that only the UN Security Council has the power to force any country to do anything by stating that "Nothing contained in the present Charter shall authorize the United Nations to intervene in matters which are essentially within the domestic jurisdiction of any state or shall require the Members to submit such matters to settlement under the present Charter; but this principle shall not prejudice the application of enforcement measures under [Chapter VII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapter_VII_of_the_United_Nations_Charter)." (Only the Security Council can institute Chapter VII enforcement measures.)

In other words, they only intervene when there is a conflict (threat to the peace, breach of the peace, act of aggression) in a country.

Comment: This reads a little absolutist and is overly charitable to the UN with regards to staying true to their mission.  You can't speak for the future in such a way.  Remember this is the same organization that was guilty of the Saddam Hussein oil for food fraud and several child rape and pedophile rackets

Comment: @KDog The question is about the UN's endorsing a political candidate. Not about their fraud cases.

Comment: My point is you can't always count on the UN staying true to it's founding principles, and they do often stray.

Comment: @KDog that is as pointless of a claim as claiming that you can not count on Republican party members not killing and raping you, because of [Ted Bundy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_Bundy).

Comment: @SJuan76 Institutional fraud and sodomy rings at the very highest levels of office are not the same thing as some sociopath with a loose and tenuous affiliation to the national GOP, if at all.

Comment: @KDog "at the very highest levels of office" There were cases of child abuse by UN deployed troops, but where do the "highest levels" come from? Do you have **respectable** references or it is another "secret basement and tunnels" *intelligence work*?

Comment: I was referring to the Oil for Food scandal that involved that involved the Secretary General's son, Kojo Anan.

Comment: @SJuan76 Although your question on how high up in the UN the various pedophilia rape rings went is a good one.  Suggest you open it as a new question.

Comment: @KDog If you knew that the paedophilic ring did not involve the higher level of the UN, why did you affirm that it did, then? Because that is what `Institutional fraud and sodomy rings at the very highest levels of office` means. And whatever doubts you have, Kofi Annan (that is his name) was not prosecuted for the FFO scandal; if we are going to ignore pressumption of innocence I would like to talk about a politician who made profit by knowingly making false statements about some University (which, you may know, is called **fraud**) or some general that did share intel without authorization.

Comment: I didn't say I didn't know.  I said open the question: The range of sexual abuse includes reported rapes of young Congolese girls by U.N. troops; an Internet pedophile ring run from Congo by Didier Bourguet, a senior U.N. official from France; a colonel from South Africa accused of molesting his teenage male translators; and estimates of hundreds of underage girls having babies fathered by U.N. soldiers who have been able to simply leave their children and their crimes behind

Comment: http://abcnews.go.com/Blotter/UnitedNations/story?id=489306&page=1

Comment: @KDog - "an Internet pedophile ring ... senior U.N. official from France."  ACTUAL CASE - Bourget was not a "senior UN official," we was a UN employee, a mechanic, who's job was maintaining fleet vehicles.  He was charged with raping girls.  He says he paid for the sex and didn't know they were underaged, but the court didn't buy that story.  He taped the sex and had it on his computer, which means he was charged with possession of illegal pornographic materials.  There is no evidence or claims, in court, of any "Internet pedophile ring."  http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/europe/7607106.stm

Comment: There was also nothing about the UN program or his position there that facilitated his misdeeds.  Any person in the Congo for any reason would have been able to do the same thing.  He was not enabled or sheltered by the UN, so somehow linking his actions to the UN as evidence of the UN, as an organization, not being above-board is a pretty specious link.